# Rails find all with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have what I think is a very simple problem (famous last words)...

I have a `Category` model that `has_and_belongs_to_many` `Events`. I want to construct a simple and efficient query that finds all categories that have 1 or more events. (using Rails 3)

I'm sure I'm having a dumb moment here - any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
Category.find :all,
  :conditions => 'id in (select distinct category_id from categories_events)'
```

You could also add this as a named scope to your `Category` class so that you can say `Category.with_events` e.g.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :with_events, 
    :conditions => 'id in (select distinct category_id from categories_events)'
end
```